# how to find my data from mongodb in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, connection

```
import express from 'express'
import child_process ,{execSync}from 'child_process'
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
const app=express();
const connectDB = async() => {
    mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/test')
    const dockSchema  = new mongoose.Schema({
        image:String,
        run:String,
        close:String
    })
    const dock = mongoose.model('docker',dockSchema)
    const data = await dock.find();
    console.warn(data)
    console.log("connection done")
}
connectDB();

app.get("/", (_req,res)=>{
    res.send("hello from satyam")
})
app.listen(8000,()=>console.log("use local host at port 8000"))
output:
use local host at port 8000
[]
connection done
```

why show this blank array ...mongodb is running

i will try to get data from mongodb in node js console.but i find empty array